# Cakephp change Admin Prefix

Tags: .htaccess, cakephp, url-rewriting, cakephp-1.3, routes

I have developed a huge admin panel in cakePHP which i can access with SITE_URL/admin.Now i want to change this url by SITE_URL/jpaneladmin without changing any of my functions which i have defiuned with admin_ prefix. Any idea(s)?

any routing rule i can pass to change this url?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Setup routes:

```
Router::connect('/jpaneladmin/:controller', array('action' => 'index', 'prefix' => 'admin', 'admin' => true));
Router::connect('/jpaneladmin/:controller/:action/*', array('prefix' => 'admin', 'admin' => true));
```

Comment: but still my redirects and links are showing me /admin links and on click of those link missconception and error happening

Comment: i have tried this but my website is wholly developed so each links i have put having uyrl of admin for that what i should do...i have to match url like we are converting links using sluggable url lib extension so do you have any idea regardiong that scenario so please help me out ...its urgent for me...

Comment: If you have specified all urls using the array format then there shouldn't be any problem, they would be automatically updated based on new routes. But if you ignored best practices and specified them as simple string like "/admin/foo/bar" then there's no option but yo manually change each of them.

Comment: is this the same implementation on CakePHP 2.x? because I'm having difficulty in to getting it work. it still identifies "jpaneladmin" as a controller, although your first line tries to communicate otherwise